# Can SonarQube project administrators delete a project via the API?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.4. The [SonarQube's API documentation](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/projects) says that the **POST api/projects/destroy** method requires *Administer System* permission.

However, users having the Administer Project role can delete their projects via the web interface selecting the **Deletion** option in the **Project Configuration** menu.

Why can't "project administrators" use the API to delete the projects they administer? Or is there a way? I've tried and I got this error:

```
$ curl -u user:password -X POST "https://sonar.cpqd.com.br/api/projects/destroy?id=123456789"
{"err_code":401,"err_msg":"Unauthorized"}%
```

Comment: which version of SonarQube are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using version 4.5.4.

Comment: you should edit the question to include this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the documentation you provide points to http://nemo.sonarqube.org/ which is running SonarQube 5.1, not the version you are using.

Fortunately, there is no change regarding permissions checks on the WS `/api/projects/destroy` between 4.5 and 5.1 and what you request is not implemented: Administer System permission is required, project administer permission is not enough.

In 5.2, this WS is replaced by WS `/api/project/delete` which requires 'Administer System' permission or 'Administer' permission on the project.

Comment: This means that on version 5.2 project admins will be able to delete projects via the API, which is great and answers my question. Thanks!